# Angular 2 ParamMap

Tags: angular2-routing

I try to learn Angular 2 through Tour of Heroes on the site angular.io, now I'm get in stuck on router method >> ParamMap, I add line:

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
```

but compiler shows **error "Module 'path...' has no exported member 'ParamMap'"**

I built my project via Angular CLI.

**file package.json**

```js
@angular/router": "^3.3.1"
```

I searched in folder @angular/router/src/index.d.ts export ParamMap but I didn't find, into API but the site says path: router/src/shared.ts but I also didn't  find this class there.
I suggest that this class was removed in new versions or vice versa added in new Angular 4. 
How I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this problem, here's how to upgrade your Angular version from 2 or 3 to the latest in npm.

**On Unix**

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

**On Windows**

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

Solution found here: https://progblog.io/How-to-upgrade-to-Angular-4/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, I reinstalled angular-cli after than I remove node_modules folder in my project, after than I change my package.json with new dependencies (angular4 etc.) after than install all dependencies and run server, After that I didn't get error.